# MassTransit consume all messages from the queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I use **Masstransit RabbitMQ**. As a consumer, only consume events when they are published in the queue. In the above example, how can I get all the **SubmitOrder** as list from the queue with a single request(consume)?

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("order-service", e =>
                {
                    //here i want to get all SubmitOrder as list
                    e.Handler<SubmitOrder>(async context =>
                    {
                        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Submit Order Received: {context.Message.OrderId}");
                    });
                });
            });
```

In a job, I need to retrieve all messages from a queue, then use that list to process them.
I have a gateway that publishes messages in a queue, and then I have a job that receives the messages from the queue and processes them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't generally how messaging works. With MassTransit, you can have messages delivered individually, so that each is consumed atomically. Or you can use a [batch consumer](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/consumers#batch-consumers) to have multiple messages delivered at once.

Thinking that you can just "get all the messages" from a queue is not the way one should ever think, there could literally be millions and millions of messages in the queue. And you definitely would not process multiple `SubmitOrder` style messages as a batch anyway. Architecturally, it's just a really bad idea.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Since there is a queue structure in place, it's not advisable to pop all the data from it. A batch consumer was exactly what I needed. Thanks